Playsinline issue with opentok-react in latest safari version 17+
enter image description here
Facing plays inline like overlay issue which occurs during video call which is happening more over in IOS safari latest version, whenever video was switched to off and on the overlay screen may occurs sometime.
Don't want that overlay screen to appear

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
